# Provider name cannot be null error using Active Directory

Tags: active-directory-module

After successfully deploying the AD module in Sitecore, complete with members, roles, and profiles, we have now encountered an issue where Sitecore crashes when adding in a second domain.

[image: Error message]

What is causing this error and is it possible to overcome it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out if you RTFM you can avoid this issue.

I found a clue in this [post](http://developmentsitecore.blogspot.com/2016/01/issue-sitecore-ad-module-throws-error.html) where the author mentions the ports required. Further reading, the installation [document](https://dev.sitecore.net/Downloads/Active_Directory/1_3/Active_Directory_1_3.aspx) provided on the Sitecore portal indicates the required ports.

> 2.1.1 Prerequisites
>
> Active Directory requires that port 389 is open by default:
>
> ```
> 389 — for client communications
> 445 — for Active Directory Profile Provider
> ```

After running some tests using `Test-NetConnection`, I was able to confirm that the port is not open for the second domain controller.

[image: Testing]

#### Options

1. Remove profile settings for the second domain and live without those properties populating.
2. Get port 445 opened.

Comment: Man, I would almost log that as a bug for bad error handling and messaging. Nice find.